# Need to get user email id as input and send logs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, input, groovy

I have a shell script wil runs on taking user inputs and send logs to users when fails syntax I use: ./script.sh env usecase emailid 
Now am doing a jenkins build and not sure on how to get user input for email id . I am currently getting 2 inputs using choice parameter.
I want user to give email id and its passed as a parameter .

```
@Library('Shared@release/v1')
import jenkins.BuildSupport

properties([parameters([choice(choices: ['dev''uat', 'prod'], description: 'Select the Environment', name: 'ENVIRONMENT'), choice(choices: ['a1','a2','all'], description: 'Select the Service', name: 'SERVICENAME')])])

node{  
    WORKSPACE = pwd()

    //checkout code from shared library 
    stage ('Code Checkout'){
    codeCheckout
    }   

    //post build work
    stage('Executing Health Check') {
    withEnv(["WORKSPACE=${WORKSPACE}","ENVIRONMENT=${params.ENVIRONMENT}","SERVICENAME=${params.SERVICENAME}",]) {
            sh '''
            set +x  
            ls -l
            ./script.sh ${ENVIRONMENT} ${SERVICENAME} 
            '''
        }  
   }
}
```

I need the `script.sh` to take 3rd parameter which will be the email id entered by user

Comment: Are you asking how to add a third input parameter to the job, or are you asking how to make the shell script take the parameter?

Comment: my shell script runs fine with 3rd parameter in linux my question is how to add 3rd parameter in jenkins which will allow user to type in email id and take that as 3rd parameter like $3 in shell

Comment: OK, that's what I added to your example in my answer, give it a try.

Comment: sure will check and update thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So couple of things going on here. First, you need to add a string parameter to ask the user for input, then you need to pass that to the shell script, and then you need to make sure the shell script can use it.

I don't see the need for withEnv, you can pass variables to a script without that.

Just make sure your shell script is getting the EMAIL_ADDRESS from $3

```
#!groovy

@Library('Shared@release/v1')
import jenkins.BuildSupport

properties([parameters([string(name: 'EMAIL_ADDRESS', description: 'Enter the email address'), choice(choices: ['dev','uat','prod'], description: 'Select the Environment', name: 'ENVIRONMENT'), choice(choices: ['a1','a2','all'], description: 'Select the Service', name: 'SERVICENAME')])])

node{  
    WORKSPACE = pwd()

    //checkout code from shared library 
    stage ('Code Checkout'){
    codeCheckout
    }   

    //post build work
    stage('Executing Health Check') { 
       sh '''
          set +x  
          ls -l
          ./script.sh $ENVIRONMENT $SERVICENAME $EMAIL_ADDRESS
       '''
    }
}
```

Comment: now its taking the email id as input but not sending an email. email is working fine from linux .

Comment: echo "$2 Failed!!Please find log" |mailx -s "Script Failed in $env" -a $LOGFILE $3

Comment: OK well your question was about Jenkins, please mark the answer as correct if it was correct. Ask another about the email.

Comment: Is there a way the Jenkins can send me the log to the email id? my shell script log is saved as $LOGFILE

Comment: It can, look into configuring Jenkins to send email, simple setup, and then look into "emailext", I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Example of sending email from Jenkins scripted pipeline/ Groovy

```
    stage('Email the results') {
        emailext attachLog: true,
            attachmentsPattern: '*',
            to: "${EMAIL_ADDRESS}",
            subject: "${currentBuild.currentResult} - ${ENVIRONMENT} ${SERVICE}",
            body: """
Blah blah blah
"""
    }
```

Comment: in my script.sh the logs are curently saved under $LOGFILE which is /tmp location  , can i specify $logfile the path and get that in email?

Comment: What I would suggest is to use the Jenkins environmental variable $WORKSPACE as the destination for your logs (the workspace of the Jenkins job), and then emailext will find them easily and attach them. What I mean by that is to use $WORKSPACE in your "script.sh", not the Jenkins job itself.

Comment: will try and update you . Thank you as of now getting error .WorkflowScript: 30: unexpected token: @ @ line 30, column 31.
               to: "${jonsnow@lfsc.com}",